# Filtering from Tuesday to Tuesday Each Week

Tags: vba

I have a code (below) where I can filter based on last week using just the date function and subtracting by 7. Is there a way I can do this where I filter from say Tuesday to Tuesday each week? I know there is the vbTuesday function but not sure why I can't recall the correct way to pull that.

See code:

```
Dim j As Integer,
j = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Date and Time Completed", Range("A1:BG1"), 0)
Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter Field:=j, Criteria1:=">=" & CLng(Date - 7)
```

Comment: Why would you want an 8 day week?

Comment: I guess more so just trying to tag transactions within a week span. So Wednesday - Tuesday may be a better call out, but in essence trying to capture all the activity that has happened since the last week.

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the date condition as as string-date:

`Criteria1:=">=" & Format(Date - 7, "dd\/mm\/yyyy")`

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't solve the problem. I am looking to filter between dates, not necessarily the formatting of the date itself.

Answer (score 0):

First, find the last Tuesday and the Wednesday before and format these.

```vb
Dim PreviousWednesday As String
Dim LastTuesday As String

PreviousWednesday = Format(DateAdd("ww", -1, DatePreviousWeekday(date, vbWednesday)), "m\/d\/yyyy")
LastTuesday = Format(DatePreviousWeekday(date, vbTuesday), "m\/d\/yyyy")

' To debug:
? PreviousWednesday, LastTuesday
' Result:
' 7/6/2022      7/12/2022
```

Those functions are from module `DateFind.bas` from my library [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date).

Then compose the criteria:

```vb
Criteria1:=">=" & PreviousWednesday & "", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & LastTuesday & ""
```

Comment: I'm receiving an error when running this code

Comment: What error, please?